# Plot timezones over the world map in R

Tags: r, timezone, maps

Hi folks: could anyone give me some hints about plotting timezones grid using polygons over the world map in R? I use maps to get the world layout, but where to get coordinates of timezones polygons?

Ultimately, I would love to get something [like this](http://www.timeanddate.com/time/map/about.html), coloring timezones according to some values from my analyses. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your question is just *where* to get time zone shapefiles for plotting, then you can get some from http://efele.net/maps/tz/world/.

Comment: Interesting data, however, I assume, it is meant to be used by some other software, not R. I tried `shapefiles` library, - R can't plot the data out of the box - I think multi-polygones mess things up. Secondly, I am not sure how to handle the TZ data in this set...

Comment: @PavelSenin You may have better luck with `readShapeSpatial` in the `maptools` package.